# Having another Where Filter on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am trying to do a search and would only like to return the users with status of 1,4. Although when I try to use this, it grabs them all and ignores my last where.

```
$officiants = Officiant::where('status',1)
                        ->where('email', 'like',  '%'.$item.'%')
                        ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
                        ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
                        ->whereIn('status', [1,4])
                        ->get();
```

I have also tried

```
$officiants = Officiant::where('status',1)
                        ->where('email', 'like',  '%'.$item.'%')
                        ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
                        ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
                        ->where('status', 1)
                        ->where('status', 4)
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out

```
   $officiants = Officiant::where('status', 1)
                                    ->orWhere('status', 4)
                                    ->where(function ($query) use ($item) {
                                      $query->where('email', 'like',  '%'.$item.'%')
                                            ->where('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
                                            ->where('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%');
                                    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need to understand how where chaining and orWhere chaining works in Laravel.

When you say `$query->where(..a..)->orWhere(..b..)->where(..c..)->orWhere(..d..)` it will evaluate to: `(a || (b && c) || d)`. Where you may have intended `((a || b) && (c || d))` or you may have intended `((a && c) || b || d)`. This is why when you need advanced where clauses, use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping)

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this :

```
$officiants = Officiant::where('status',1)
    ->where(function($query) use($item){
        $query->where('email', 'like',  '%'.$item.'%')
            ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
            ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%'.$item.'%')
    })
        ->whereIn('status', [1,4])
        ->get();
```

note : this is not tested